# How to add mouse cursor to Xephyr?

Tags: xorg, python, mouse

I'm using `pyvirtualdisplay` (which launches `Xephyr`) and `xdotool` to automate mouse movements. While I know it works, I can't see the mouse cursor. Is it possible to add it? I've added `fluxbox` window manager with `subprocess.Popen`. Is there some application to draw the cursor in the same window?

Comment: there is a flag `-retro` but that requires controlling the exec of Xephyr

Answer (score 1):

Use Xephyr `-softCursor` parameter